# Why do I need rebinding/shadowing when I can have mutable variable binding?

Tags: rust

Why do I need rebinding/shadowing when I can have mutable variable binding? Consider:

```
let x = a();
let x = b(x);
```

vs.

```
let mut x = a();
x = b(x);
```

Mutable variable binding allows a mutable borrow of that variable over this.
But does shadowing have some advantages over mutable bindings?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Because the two have totally different effects.**

---

To really understand what is going on, we need to start at the beginning: what is a binding? What does binding mean?

Let's consider a simple function: `fn hello() -> String;`.

When invoking this function like so:

```
fn main() {
    hello();
}
```

What happens?

The function returns a `String`, which is promptly discarded (executing `Drop` as it is thereby freeing its memory).

The result is dropped because it was not bound to a variable name, and the rules of the language say that if not bound then it can be promptly dropped<sup>1</sup>.

If we bind this result, however, we prolong the life of this value, and we can access it via this binding... for a while.

```
fn main() {
    let value = hello();

    std::mem::drop(value);

    println!("{}", value); // Error: moved out of value
}
```

**This** is the issue at hand: in Rust, the lifetime of a value is independent from the scope of a binding.

A value need not even be dropped before its binding exits its scope: it can be transferred to another (similar to returning from a function).

```
fn main() {
    let x;
    {
        let y = hello();
        x = y;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *the same happens if binding to `_`*.

---

So, now we armed with the fact that bindings and values differ, let's examine the two snippets.

A first shadowing snippet, differing from yours:

```
fn main() {
    let x = a();
    let x = b();
}
```

Steps, in order:

- The expression `a()` creates a value, which is bound to `x`
- The expression `b()` creates a value, which is bound to `x`
- The value created by `b()` is dropped
- The value created by `a()` is dropped

Note that the fact that `x` is re-bound does not affect the lifetime of the value that was previously bound.

Technically, it behaves exactly as if the result of `b()` was bound to `y`, with the sole exception that the previous `x` binding is not accessible while `y` is in scope.

Now, the mutable snippet:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = a();
    x = b();
}
```

Steps, in order:

- The expression `a()` creates a value, which is bound to `x`
- The expression `b()` creates a value, which is bound to `x`, and the previous value (created by `a()`) is dropped
- The value created by `b()` is dropped

Once again, accessing the previous value is impossible, however whilst with shadowing it's impossible temporarily (if shadowing in a smaller scope), with assignment it's impossible forever since the value is dropped.

Comment: A wonderful answer that made the light bulb finally switch on. Shouldn't `x = y;` within the function `fn main() {
    let x;
    {
        let y = hello();
        x = y;
    }
    println!("{}", x);
}` be `let x = y;` Also, can you please clarify to newbies like me why value created by 'b' is dropped before the value created by 'a'. Trying to make sure I absorb this fully.

Comment: @Kayote: (1) no I really mean `x = y;`. `let x;` is a way to declare a binding in advance without actually binding it (yet). This is used here to have the value assigned to `y` *escape* its scope. (2) at the end of a lexical scope, the variables are destroyed in *reverse order* of their creation; this is necessary so that a variable can *refer* to one declared before it safely. For example, consider `let vec = vec!(1, 2); let x = &vec[0];`: if `vec` were destroyed first, `x` would point to freed memory!

Comment: Prefect & makes sense. Thank you again.

Comment: Does it mean that shadowing could lead to some kind of memory leak? In the snippet `fn main() { let x = a(); let x = b(); }`, the value created by `a()` could last till the end of the process, while there is no other place using it at all.

Comment: @EricZheng: Yes and no. The value created by `a()` will live until the end of the lexical scope, I'll leave it up to you to decide whether this constitute a memory leak or not in your case. To reason about, you can use the idea of *frame slots* and rewrite the code above to `fn main() {`, `frame [0] = a();`, `x = 0;`, `frame[1] = b();`, `x = 1;`, `}`. `x` is just the name of the frame slot in which the value lives; if you reassign the name you may not be able to access the value any longer, but the compiler still can, because it's got access to the stack frame itself.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this answer shows how the two are different and how they work; I'm no closer to understanding ***why*** the feature was built into the language in the first place, especially when you could've easily said `let x = a(); let y = b();` instead of using shadowing to re-bind `x` twice.

Comment: @code_dredd: This answer assumes having the same name is desirable, since in the OP the same name is reused. The question of whether shadowing is desirable instead of just using a different name is a separate question that all language designers have to think about; although I'm not sure how it would be received on StackOverflow, it's certainly a question that interests me.

Answer (score 14):

One answer I found myself: shadowing can change variable type.

```
let x = get_some_string();
let x = x.smart_parse_int();
```

Comment: Not only that. You also can change mutability (which is common usecase): `let mut foo = Foo::new(); /* build foo */ let foo = foo; // make foo immutable`.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier: Note that you can simply use block expressions for that, `let foo = { let mut foo = Foo::new(); ...; foo };`